# Gitlab and YouTrack in same docker VCS not work

Tags: gitlab, version-control, traefik, youtrack

I have docker container installed with Gitlab community and at the same time on the same YouTrack server. When I want to connect Gitlab with YouTrack using VCS, I get this error:

> The specified URL does not point to an accessible GitLab repository. Please make sure the URL is correct and the user has access to the repository.

As reverse proxy, I use traefik.

I tried to set the ufw 443 port according to other instructions, but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a Docker network, DNS resolution is handled firstly by Docker. I am figuring this issue is one of two things.

1. **Docker container network dns resolution**

If both of the containers exist on the same docker network, you may find success in referring to the container by its container name, such as `gitlab`. e.g.

- instead of `https://gitlab.your.domain`, use `http://gitlab`
- instead of `ssh://gitlab.your.domain:22`, use `ssh://gitlab:22`

This option may not be relevant if YouTrack is not also containerized on this host.

2. **Resolve traefik/gitlab hostnames to local**

I would bet that your network doesn't know how to handle the public hostname resolving to traefik, who is then supposed to pass traffic to gitlab. Things get 'weird' (technical term) when the hostname resolves to an IP that happens to be the WAN IP/gateway for the server/LAN.

With this, you could try a local `/etc/hosts` alias, so that any requests from within this server to whatever your CNAME/A record for Traefik is, are resolved locally immediately to the local system. Example below.

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    traefik.your.domain
```